# Registering an account on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I go to the Minecraft website, I am wondering on how to register an account so I look it up and everything says there is a register link at the top right corner in the website, but all mine says is login/redeem a code. I need help please I just need the link.

Comment: I think that must be a browser-related problem. Do you have a lot of ad- and script-blocking plugins, perhaps? I suggest you try another browser. In any case, this problem itself has nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not game-related (likely browser-related).

Comment: @Joachim I see where you're coming from, but I think this is enough related to be on-topic. Also my script blockers don't wreck it, and even if they were preventing it the button would be visible as it is very uncommon for sites to react to blocked scripts unless it be the annoying "I NOTICE U HAVE AN AD BLOCKER NOW DONATE ME $$$". Since the button isn't visible I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As of December 1st, **you will now use your Microsoft account to log in and buy.**

For registration, simply click the green button in the centre of the page.
[image: To]

On the next screen, click "Computer", your OS, then "Minecraft: Java Edition" (if you selected Windows). You should then get:
[image: Register account]
Then press the Buy button. You'll be directed to create a Microsoft account if you do not have one, or you'll be asked to log in. After logging in, you will be directed to the purchase store.

Comment: Does Microsoft own Minecraft now?! Is it soon going to be known as Microcraft?

Comment: Microsoft has owned minecraft since 2014.  This was a decision made by mojang to improve account security and account support response times.